# Why is Rails server `tap`-ped in Rails source code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails source code contains this piece added by [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1b816d502444ce2b3153d8c689d0057f1c257eee/railties/lib/rails/commands.rb), which starts a rails server:

```
  Rails::Server.new.tap do |server|
    # We need to require application after the server sets environment,
    # otherwise the --environment option given to the server won't propagate.
    require APP_PATH
    Dir.chdir(Rails.application.root)
    server.start
  end
```

I wonder why method `tap` is used. Per my understanding, `tap` is designed to chain methods. However, nothing is chained here. Also, per my understanding, it will never exit from `server.start`. So, it doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it completely answers the question, but I believe the point of this, in general, is to not just define a "mystery" local variable for any-old scope in a file. Instead, one can give local variables an explicit scope using `.tap` with a block (since the local variable is removed from memory at the end of the block). So it may be that they're just trying to define the scope mentally here (i.e. "this variable is only needed for this code here").

**UPDATE**:

Here's the article I read a while back on this: http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2144-scope-a-variable-to-a-block-in-your-template-code

Comment: You and Amadan answered generally the same thing at the same time. I asked him and want to ask you, whether it's a common pattern to restrict scope?

Comment: It's somewhat common in Rails code. I've seen it here and there. In gems too. It just depends who's coding, who knows the pattern, and how right it feels for the situation I guess. But it makes sense, I think. I use it maybe 5% of the time myself.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for sure that it is the reason, but it restricts the variable `server` as local to that block. This has no impact on the functionality of the code, since `server` is not referred to at all in the rest of the code, but it is helpful to one reading the code:

```
server = Rails::Server.new
require APP_PATH
Dir.chdir(Rails.application.root)
server.start
```

has the same semantics, but leaves `server` in scope. This makes the reader inspect the rest of the code to see if anything else is using `server`. In the original example, you know that only those three lines use `server`, and that is it.

Comment: I understand scoping concern. However, is this a common pattern to use tap to restrict scope?